# Using CodeDeploy ValidateService Hook with Python Application

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-code-deploy, aws-codepipeline

I have an heavy app hosted on AWS.
I use CodeDeploy & Code Pipeline (updating from github) to update the servers when a new release is ready (currently running 6 ec2 instances on production environment).

I've setup the codedeploy to operate one-by-one and also defined a 300 seconds connection draining on the load balancer.

Still, my application is heavy (it loads large dictionary pickle files from the disk to the memory), the process of firing up takes about ~60 seconds. In those 60 seconds CodeDeploy marks the process of deployment to an instance as completed, causing it to join back as a healthy instance to the load balancer - this might cause errors to users trying to reach the application.

I thought about using the `ValidateService` hook, but i'm not sure how to in my case..

Any ideas on how to wait for a full load and readyness of the application before proceeding to the next instance?

This is my current AppSpec.yml

`version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: /deployment
    destination: /deployment
  - source: /webserver/src
    destination: /vagrant/webserver/src
permissions:
  - object: /deployment
    pattern: "**"
    owner: root
    mode: 644
    type:
      - directory
  - object: /webserver/src
    owner: root
    mode: 644
    except: [/webserver/src/dictionaries]
    type:
      - directory
hooks:
  ApplicationStop:
    - location: /deployment/aws_application_stop.sh
  BeforeInstall:
    - location: /deployment/aws_before_install.sh
  AfterInstall:
    - location: /deployment/aws_after_install.sh
  ApplicationStart:
    - location: /deployment/aws_application_start.sh`

Answer (score 2):

I would loop in the `ValidateService` hook, checking for the condition you expect, **OR** just sleep for 60 seconds, assuming that is the normal initialization time.

The `ValidateService` hook should do just that: make sure the service is fully running before continuing/finalizing the deployment.  That depends on your app of course.  But consider a loop that pulls a specially designed page EG `http://localhost/service-ready`.  In that URL, test and confirm anything and everything appropriate for your service. Return a `-Pending-` string if the service is not yet validated. Return a `-OK-` when everything is 100%

Perhaps loop that 10-20 times with a 10 second sleep, and exit when it returns `-OK-` then throw an error if the service never validates.